# Maven Versions Plugin, update parent recursively in multi-module project

Tags: java, maven, version, project, maven-versions-plugin

I have following maven project structure

```
pom.xml (parent)  

pom.xml (extends parent, aggregates modules)
|
|--pom.xml (extends aggregate)
```

Now, when I `mvn install` upgraded parent version and run `mvn versions:update-parent` on the aggregate project, I would except first the aggregate parent is updated and aggregate inherits the version, and sequently it's module's parents are updated for upgraded aggregate, again inheriting the version. That would make perfect sense with the fact aggregate projects just sequently builds all modules with same maven command.

However, this isn't the case with Maven Versions Plugin. The example just upgrades the aggregate parent, but leaves it's modules (inheriting it) untouched. Is this bug in the plugin? How to scope around with this issue?

I know I could run `mvn versions:set` in the aggregate to successfully update modules too, but in this case I have to specify the version (versus using *latest* parent). I know I could also make a script to figure this out, but that's dirty.

So, how do I correctly upgrade version with Maven Version Plugin, where project utilizes inheritance, aggregation and is spanned across multiple repositories, and using parent POM as single source of version declaration?

Comment: The plugin you are using the [versions-maven-plugin](https://github.com/mojohaus/versions-maven-plugin/) and not the Maven Versions Plugin...furthermore can you make an example project of your setup and create an issue on the versions-maven-plugin are...

Answer (score 4):

After the

```
mvn versions:2.1:update-parent
```

you can try the command to update the child-versions [(as given here)](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/)

```
mvn versions:update-child-modules
```

Comment: This is still the only solution I have found to make it work as expected.